# eloquent: how to handle conditional relationship

Tags: eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a table named "requests" for handling customers' requests, where it can be created by different types of users (suppliers, customers).

knowing that each type of users have it's own table, I want to build a relationship between the "request" and the createdBy user, but this relation is conditional, so if the user_type = 1, the createdBy user is supplier, while if the user_type = 2, so the createdBy user is a customer.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
public function createdBySupplier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class, 'createdBy')
        ->distinct()
        ->select('suppliers.*')
        ->join('requests', function($join) {
            $join->on('requests.createdBy', '=', 'suppliers.id')
                ->where('requests.user_type', '=', 1);
        });
    }

    public function createdByCustomer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'createdBy')
        ->distinct()
        ->select('customers.*')
        ->join('requests', function($join) {
            $join->on('requests.createdBy', '=', 'customers.id')
                ->where('requests.user_type', '=', 2);
        });
    }
```

what I want is to have only one relationship called "createdByUser()", which should know how to handle the relationship according to the "user_type" attribute, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a model for `requests` table and make the relationships within it:

```
public function createdBySupplier()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class, 'createdBy');
}

public function createdByCustomer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'createdBy');
}

public function createdByUser()
{
    return $this->user_type === 1 ? 
        $this->createdBySupplier() :
        $this->createdByCustomer();
}
```

Then use it:

```
Requests::find(1)->createdByUser;
```